# Can I change back to my initial character after finishing adventure mode

Tags: dont-starve

I had a nice survival world, playing with Wilson, then decided to start an adventure from that world. Now I finished adventure mode, I'm back in my good old sandbox, but with Maxwell. Is there any way I can get back to Wilson, while keeping the world ?

Comment: It might actually be a good thing: while Wilsons beard is nice to help survive winter & get cheap hair (for effigies), Maxwell is much more suited for underground exploration due to his high sanity regeneration. You probably have a good enough base and enough materials in your world to help survive winter - **now would be a great time to go spelunking**.

Comment: I tried but I feel uncomfortable spelunking with Maxwell's low health. I fear I have more problems with enemies than with sanity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without mods, there are only two ways to change the character:

1. Finish your world by going through the teleportato. You can choose any new character for the next level, but it generates a new world. You can bring stuff along though.
2. Finish adventure mode. It returns you to your original world, but with the character you freed.

Since you want to keep your current world, and the character you want is right now the one locked in adventure mode, the solution is to **finish adventure mode again from your current world**.

Do note: if you play another save, finish adventure mode there, and lock someone else on the throne, it transfers between saves.

Comment: I will try, but it could be hard with Maxwell :) (for me).